# Compute shader terrain seams

Tags: unity-game-engine, hlsl, compute-shader

I'm creating a terrain generator in Unity. Currently working on LOD when I got stuck. My compute shader is generating a mesh from a heightmap.

The issue I'm facing is the seam between neighboring chunks with different level of detail.
Illustration:

```
*---*---*
|\  |\  |
|  \|  \|
*---*---*
*-*-*-*-*
|\|\|\|\|
*-*-*-*-*
```

These triangles are generated by:

```
if (x> 0 && y> 0)
{
    int triangleId = ((x* (mapSize-1) + y) - (mapSize)) * 6;

    int A = mapSize * x+ y;
    int B = mapSize * x+ y- 1;
    int C = mapSize * (x- 1) + y- 1;
    int D = mapSize * (x- 1) + y; 

    triangleBuffer[triangleId++] = A;
    triangleBuffer[triangleId++] = B;
    triangleBuffer[triangleId++] = C;

    triangleBuffer[triangleId++] = C;
    triangleBuffer[triangleId++] = D;
    triangleBuffer[triangleId++] = A; 
}
```

I have an idea of how I'd like to solve it, but as I'm quite new to shaders I'd like some help.

My proposed solution:
When creating triangles for a chunk bordering a chunk with a lower level of detail, skip every other vertex. Illustration:

```
*---*---*
|\  |\  |
|  \|  \|
*---*---*
*-*-*-*-*
|\ /|\ /|
*-*-*-*-*
```

I tried writing this and it worked for one edge, but the shader became quite complex when trying to solve for multiple edges, and filled with if statements (which I've heard is bad for gpu performance).

Is this a good solution? If so, could you give some pointers on how to solve it?